# How to use bootstrap carousel offline in only one component Angular project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm using `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",` this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcarousel-basic.html)
It works good when I'm using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` But I want to use bootstrap offline in my project.

For this I'm trying to use  something like this link `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">` but doesn't work. Also I tried to use and bootstrap file inside plugin `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` but doesn't work. It works only with online link.

Can you share with me any idea how to use it please?

Comment: You need to import the ng-bootstrap library inside your global `CSS` file.

Comment: I have a global scss file `global.scss` , I put on it `@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"`. The carousel doesn't work

Comment: The recommended way to import ng-bootstrap is `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`. About the carousel, you need to provide some code or demo so that we could analyse the problem.

Comment: First, I put `@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';` in `styles.scss` , Second. in angular.json I put `"src/scss/styles.scss",` This way functions. But I want to use bootstrap only in one component. I try to put it in `component.scss` but dosn't work. Have you any idea please?